# How to route all incoming packets to remote proxy?

Tags: iptables, kali-linux, routing, android, ufw

I have a Wi-Fi hotspot setup in Kali. Interface wlan0 on 10.10.10.1/24. I setup an Android (10.10.10.2) to proxy requests through Burp on port 10.10.10.1:9999. This is done in the Android's Wi-Fi configuration settings. But I'm noticing some apps/services ignore the proxy and contact the internet directly. I can see DNS and TCP requests in Wireshark, for example, totally ignoring the proxy settings.

I tried some `iptables` redirects to force packets that ignore the proxy setting to port 9999. Is this possible? My initial attempts at configuring iptables failed, I'm still new to iptables and couldnt figure it out.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to 9999
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to 9999
```

Basically, I need every single packet originating from 10.10.10.2 routed through 10.10.10.1:9999 to the Burp proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It is because Burp Suite is Http and Https proxy means it can only capture Http and https traffic but some apps use other protocols for data transfer as well like Whatsapp do. For more [info](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/153944/burp-with-whatsapp). Therefore you will be able to see the only http and https traffic.